# Apache Solr undefined field score field in function query

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solr-boost

I am using solr 4.10. I have to change relevance of documents based on a field boost and document score. For that, I have come to know that I should use function query. Following is the syntax of boost field in schema

```
<field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="false" default="1.0"/>
```

My first question is that can function queries be used on stored fields only?

When I try using above schema, like following query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=bank&df=keywords&fl=id&sort=pow(score,%20boost)%20asc
```

There was  some error saying like

```
sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index:
```

then I changed the schema like

```
<field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="true" default="1.0"/>
```

Then above problem was gone but a new error appeared for query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=bank&df=keywords&fl=id,pow(score,%20boost)
```

Following error appeared

```
<lst name="error">
<str name="msg">undefined field: "score"</str>
<int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
```

Where I am wrong?
Am I correct to change attributes of boost field?

Comment: Did you run the indexer (full index) after making changes in the schema.xml file?

Comment: yes, I removed all documents and index them again

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a boost function and sort just by score (default = no order param needed).

```
bf=linear(boost,100,0)
```

You may use other functions. That depends on your usecase.
Just check out the [solr docs for function queries](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery).